# Is it possible to visit Park Guell in Barcelona for free?

Tags: spain, fees-and-charges, barcelona, parks-and-gardens, catalonia

I have read on different websites that it's possible to visit the park for free if you go there early morning, before they open something.

I have two question related to this:

1. In June 2021, will it open at 7:30, 9:30 or different hour? I have found multiple versions of this on different websites, not sure which is the correct one.
2. If you enter before they open without paying, how much time are you allowed to stay there? As much as you want or until they open. Or other way.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/91418/when-did-barcelonas-park-g%c3%bcell-needed-tickets

Comment: What websites are you looking at?  Because [Park Guell](https://parkguell.barcelona/en/planning-your-visit/prices-and-times) says that 07:00 to 09:30 is reserved for for neighbors and Gaudir Més members and explicitly NOT for tourists

Comment: No, you can't. In 2014 you can go there for free, but since that date only the neighbors and in a closed schedule, can enter for free.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [write-up](https://www.totallyspaintravel.com/2013/09/06/gaudi-parc-guell-barcelona/):

- The entry fee charging began in 2013, so that'd explain your memory
- If you book a ticket for 10am, you can gain entrance to the restricted zone from 10am until 10.30am. Opening times vary depending on the time of year but in high season, for example, you can enter the restricted zone at 8am and don’t have to leave it until 9.30pm!